# EnvDTE80 Solution2 AddFromFile() throws exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, automation, envdte

In my WPF application, I'm trying to create a VS2105 solution and add an existing vc project to it using EnvDte. Creating and saving the solution goes without problems. However, when I try to add the project, it throws.

```
private void CreateSolution(string path, string projectName)
{
    var solutionName = projectName;
    // VS2015Instance is a EnvDte80.DTE2
    VS2015Instance.Solution.Create(path, solutionName);

    var projectFullPath = Path.Combine(path, @"Scripts\");
    var fullPath = Path.Combine(projectFullPath, ProjectName + ".vcxproj");

    // This call throws exception
    ((EnvDTE80.Solution2)VS2015Instance.Solution).AddFromFile(fullPath);

    var solutionFullFileName = Path.Combine(path, solutionName + ".sln");
    VS2015Instance.Solution.SaveAs(solutionFullFileName);
}
```

The exception reads:

`System.Exception: An exception was thrown while initializing part "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCLegacyEventsTranslator". at EnvDTE80.Solution2.AddFromFile(String FileName, Boolean Exclusive)`

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. What is this `VCLegacyEventsTranslator` stuff? What is the best way to do what I'm trying to do? Are there any beter alternatives?